# Retrieve data from mysql table and put it in input and update the data

Tags: php, mysql

[image]My code can retrieve data from mysql table. But I am unable to update the retrieved data. I believe the code is self-explanatory.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['app'])
{
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $acadexamo = $_POST['acadexamo'];
    $acaddivio = $_POST['acaddivio'];
    $acadpco = $_POST['acadpco'];
    $acadyearo = $_POST['acadyearo'];
    $acadspeciao = $_POST['acadspeciao'];
    $acadboardo = $_POST['acadboardo'];
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
    $sqlz = mysqli_query($db, "
         SELECT id 
         FROM recru_quali 
         WHERE app='$_SESSION[app]'");
    $rowa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlz);
    $maxqua = count($acadexamo);
    for($i=0;$i<$maxqua;$i++)


       {
        $sqla = mysqli_query($db, "
                UPDATE recru_quali 
                SET acadexam='$acadexamo[$i]',
                acaddivi='$acaddivio[$i]', 
                acadpc='$acadpco[$i]', 
                acadyear='$acadyearo[$i]', 
                acadspecia='$acadspeciao[$i]', 
                acadboard='$acadboardo[$i]' 
                WHERE id='$rowa[id]' 
                AND app = '$_SESSION[app]'");
        }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="tab"><h3 align="center">Academic Qualifications:</h3>
<table id="employee_tablezz" align="center" border="1" width="100%">
<div id="form_div">
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM recru_quali WHERE 
app='$_SESSION[app]'");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
?>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="acadexamo[]" value="<?php echo 
$row[acadexam]; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="acaddivio[]" value="<?php echo 
$row[acaddivi]; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="acadpco[]" value="<?php echo $row[acadpc]; ? 
>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="acadyearo[]" value="<?php echo 
$row[acadyear]; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="acadspeciao[]" value="<?php echo 
$row[acadspecia]; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="acadboardo[]" value="<?php echo 
$row[acadboard]; ?>"></td></tr>
</table>
<button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above code updates only one row. Please show me how to update all the rows with same app number. I have added an images. The rows have been retrieved from database and displayed them in input so that user can modify it. but it wont.

Comment: With respect to my table, I have retrieved 3 rows using while loop in input form, Now I want to update them

Comment: Are all your $_POST values arrays?  Because you are passing them to variables, and then trying to loop through them.  What I mean is that, in your loop, $acadexamo[$i]  $i is referencing an element of the array, but is $POST['acadexamo'] an indexed array?  try var_dump($POST['acadexamo']), you may find it's a string.

Comment: Also, you can try mysqli error output.  It may let you know why the update query is failing.  Also, if you can post error messages that may help other's help you  -> https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysqli_error.php

Comment: Your loop seems ok but I think the `id` in `$rowa[id]` is not changing. `var_dump($rowa[id])` and `$_SESSION[app]` also in your loop to see if it is changing. That will explained why it is updating only one row.

Comment: It doesnt give any error. It just update only one row. Now if I remove id then it updates all the rows with same value

Comment: and yes my input values are array. They have been retrieved from the table where `app=$_SESSION[app]` and I want to update them

Comment: You are updating using only one $rowa[id].  So, when you loop through   for($i=0;$i<$maxqua;$i++) your WHERE id='$rowa[id] is overwriting the array of values over top of the same id.

Comment: Also, mysqli_fetch_assoc only fetches one row from the database, if you are trying to collect multiple $rowa['id']  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

Comment: I know. Please show me how to update the rest of the rows

Comment: @jonnyjandles I have added an image file. Please take a look. Those data have been retrieved from mysql table and displayed them in input so that user can update

Comment: Check out the answer I posted.  It shows you how to fetch multiple row id's and then loop though them at the same time as the $POST arrays.

Comment: You could use [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all the results and then you can loop through them. Although TBH it would probably make more sense to pass the related IDs into the request via the POST variables, so that the row IDs are correctly associated with the relevant records. Otherwise I don't know how you can be sure you are updating the right row (especially since you haven't used an ORDER BY clause in your select query).